# Using flex display for vertically center a list?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am using grid layout for the first time and wanted to allign and justify the list items, justify works, but I can't make allign work.

I decided to use flex in the child divs so I can style the content of the website, but there is no reason to use flex in particular, if there is a better way just tell me. This is the code.

```
 <div class="parent">

    <div id="container-comp">
      <div class="divclass">
        <ul class="listclass">
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And this is the css style:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 2fr) 8fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
}
    
#container-comp { 
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; 
    background-color: tomato;
}

.divclass {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.listclass > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]
The part marked is the part of the code where I have the problem, the rest of it is all in inside the parent class.

Also how is the correct way of setting up the height? How it is by default (auto) it works well for this, but if I want to set a specific height should I use % like `grid-template-columns: 100% 1fr 3fr;`?

Comment: do you want the ui sequence down?

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting your markup so the list-items aren't nested so deeply within the grid - you can simplify here.

```
<div class="parent">
  <ul id="container-comp" class="divclass listclass">
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the list horizontally you can replace the `inline-block` with `block` chek this snippet.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 2fr) 8fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
}
    
#container-comp { 
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; 
    background-color: tomato;
}

.divclass {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.listclass > li {
    display: block; //here
}
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
    <div id="container-comp">
      <div class="divclass">
        <ul class="listclass">
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```